# how to change the DPI of an image from 72DPI to 300DPI with Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have an image of 72DPI and i want to change this to 300DPI for printing purposes,
I want all the stuff need to be done with imagick, tried with the code following but no positive results.

```
<?
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(72,72);
$im->setOption('density','300x300');
$im->readImage("test.png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $im;
?>
```

can someone help/clarify me the usage of setoption or can some one explain hot to change DPI in either iMagick or GD

Comment: try $im->setImageResolution(300, 300) instead of the setOption call

Comment: Hi Orangepill, thank you, but was not working!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

I have setted resolution as pixel/inch with 300 dpi:

```
<?php
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$im->setImageResolution(300,300);
$im->readImage("test.png");
$im->setImageFormat("png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $im;
?>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Hi ITChristian, thank you, that was really helpful but was not workinh in my server, even $im->setImageResolution(300,300); is not executing, only $im->setResolution(300,300); is running on.

Comment: ah,,finally done,, the code is working, Thank you ITChristian:)

Comment: @San it is not working for me setImageResolution, what you did to make it work?