# insert image into another image Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I need to create an image with Imagick php with white background of a certain size (45 cm wide x 32 cm high) and copy him within an image that I have in a folder in a certain fixed position.

I could help with this?

A greeting and thank you very much

Comment: check this first [How can I merge 3 images into 1 image via PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419383/how-can-i-merge-3-images-into-1-image-via-php)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[imagecopy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) is the function you need

crop image example:

```
<?php
// Create image instances
$src = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor(80, 40);

// Copy
imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 20, 13, 80, 40);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

if you just need to add a white background [imagefill](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php) is your function:

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

// set background to white
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);
```

Comment: ok editing this solution a little, I used to do what I want. 

A greeting and thank you very much

Comment: this code generates an image with the black background, as I do to have the white background?

Comment: added code needed for white background

Comment: I love you, you know right?? xDxD

One last thing, the new imagen have only 72 DPI, how can change it to have 300 DPI?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585457/how-to-change-the-dpi-of-an-image-from-72dpi-to-300dpi-with-imagick 
i can't know if you love me unless you upvote my answer :P

Comment: i can´t upvote your answer because i dont have 15 point to reputation, sorry :(